# Event id 1110 on Server 2003 Std R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I keep getting event 1110 on my windows server std 2003 R2 with SP2. It started when I tried to implement Group policy. The description of the event is as below:

Event Type: Error
Event Source: Userenv
Event Category: None
Event ID: 1110
Date:  7/5/2010
Time:  7:19:34 AM
User:  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Computer: HPSERVER
Description:
Attempt to determine whether user and machine accounts are in the same forest failed (The interface is unknown. ).

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Also on my domain controller, when I go Administrative Tools > Domain security Policy or Domain controller security policy, it gives me Group Policy Error > "Failed to open group policy object. You may not have appropriate rights." The details for error is "The speicified error does not exist or could not be contacted.".. But everything looks fine on my domain.

Please let me know if you have any opinion regarding this problem. I really appreiciate your answers..

Thank you,
Hemal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean it started when you tried to implement group policy? In every AD domain there are two default group policy objects: Default Domain Policy and Default Domain Controllers Policy. These gpo's are "implemented" by default. Did you modify either of these? did you create a new GPO and link it to the domain? You need to give us more details on what you've done.

Comment: Sorry What I meant it by it, I createdd GPO to change domain users Internet home page and link it to our domain. It worked fine without any issues. Every user has the same home page now. But after that I'm getting this Event....

Comment: Unlink the new GPO from the domain and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Hi Joeqwerty,

That's the first thing I tried without any result. The weierd thing is I can access the Group policy via  Group Policy Management (C:\WINDOWS\system32\gpmc.msc) but if I go ADMIN TOOLS > Domain security/Domain controller security policy, it's giving me that"Failed to open GPO" message..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try rebooting the server.

Comment: Ok.. I am going to try that and will let you know...

Thank you very much for your time and help...

Comment: Hi Jowqwerty,

That was the solution.. Reboot the server and All Well... 

Thank you again buddy for you help,
Hemal

Comment: Glad to help...